# ANTLR: syntax with or and once

Tags: typescript, antlr4

I want to create grammar with ANTLR and to allow 3 parts in the syntax:

`toAddress | fromAddress | subject`

The user can choose to write any of them just once but the order is not restricted, examples:

1. `to: email1@compaby.com from: email2@company.com` --> ok
2. `from: email1@company.com` --> ok
3. `to: email1@company.com to: email2@company.com` --> error

any help will be appreciated.

```
searchQueryLang
    : (toAddress | fromAddress | subject)*
    | freeText
    ;

toAddress: TO addressValue;
fromAddress: FROM addressValue;
subject: SUBJECT subjectValue;
freeText: anyValue;

TO: T O (':');
FROM: F R O M (':');
SUBJECT: S U B J E C T (':');
SPACES
    : [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> skip
    ;

addressValue    : (ANYTHING | NAME)?;
anyValue        : (ANYTHING | NAME)+;
subjectValue    : SUBJECT_TYPE+;
NAME            : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_' | '@' | '/' | '#' | '.' | '\u0080'..'\uFFFF')+;
ANYTHING        : [A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z\u0080-\uFFFF_]+;
SUBJECT_TYPE: '"' ~'"'* '"';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This request comes up periodically. It’s not possible to specify the “multiple values in any order but only once” rule in ANTLR.

Just use what you have and edit the resulting parse tree for duplicates. (Bonus, you gat produce your own, easily understood error message.